# Obtaining two values from two inputs to make subject line

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form which I am submitting which captures the subject line which is a hidden field and has a value of 'Faulty Item'

https://jsfiddle.net/k8tnns73/

```
$(document).ready (function(){
     $('#zendesk_field_zen_subject input').val('Faulty Item');
});
```

What i require is when the form is posted that the subject line 'Faulty Item' is captured like so but also the order number entered value is appended to the subject line on form submission.

I have tried the following but to no avail:-

```
$(document).ready (function(){
     $('#zendesk_field_zen_subject input').val('Faulty Item')&&('#45354949').val();
});
```

is there a method in jQuery that will allow me to do this?

Comment: is #45354949 the order number or an actual HTML element?

Comment: It is an actual HTML element, I want to capture the value of what was entered in the input

Answer (score 0):

You can read them into variables and then do with them as you please:

```
$(document).ready (function(){
    var faulty = $('#zendesk_field_zen_subject input').val('Faulty Item');
    var otherField = $('#45354949').val();

    // do what you would like with the two fields
    //...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `#45354949` is an order number and not a HTML element, you can do this.

```js
$(document).ready (function(){
    
    //Select the input 
    var subject = $('#zendesk_field_zen_subject input');
    
    //Store order number in a variable
    var orderNumber = '#45354949';

    //Use this to obtain order number from an element instead
    //var orderNumber = $('#myElement').val();
    
    // Select the input and make the value faulty item + order number
    var finalSubject = subject.val('Faulty Item '+orderNumber);
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="zendesk_field_zen_subject">
 <input type="text">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `+` instead of `&&` to append the values as shown below.
I have added extra space in between the two values

```
$(document).ready (function(){
     $('#zendesk_field_zen_subject input').val('Faulty Item') +' '+ $('#45354949').val();
});
```